# Windows Form App crashes in Server 2008 obtaining Firewall Manager

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I wrote a small C# application to do firewall tasks like block IPs, enable/disable the firewall, etc. It works perfectly on Windows 7 x64 but as soon as I try it on Windows Server 2008 x64 it crashes. This is what my code looks like where its crashing...

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
  private INetFwMgr FWManager;

  public frmMain()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false);
    FWManager = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);

    if (getFirewallStatus() == true)
        UpdateFirewallStatus(true);
    else
        UpdateFirewallStatus(false);

    ListOpenPorts();
  }
}
```

The error is something along these lines...

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: brutalnt.exe
Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 4ed589c8
Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
```

When I removed the lines to obtain the Firewall Manager, it started up fine. So do I need to obtain it differently in Server 2008?

Comment: Could you change the second parameter in the call to GetTypeFromProgId to true and then wrap it in a try/catch to see if you get a specific exception thrown? See the example at; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y1yb3w3(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: It says "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800706d9"

Comment: OK. Maybe take a look at the details of the COMException like HResult and see if it provides any more specific information. Take a look at; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1(v=VS.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx

Comment: Figured it out. The machine I was testing it on, I had broken pretty badly trying to revert an Active Directory installed, which screwed up the Firewall. Works fine now, thank you!

Comment: Well done. Good to see you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was Answered in the comments, but the issue was with the machine's Active Directory installation and a broken Firewall.